# Styling for a Header text breaks layout of a background image

Tags: html, css

I created the background image `class="Background"` Fitted to the screen.
But when i add styling css to a header `class="Greetings"` to create text on a website, the background layout breaks.

How to stop this from occuring?
HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Background"></div>
    <div class="Greetings">
      <h1>
        The City Crown <br />
        One of a Kind Place
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="Buttonmenu">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.Background {
  background: url(./Images/IndexBackground.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.Greetings {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use position fixed for background image div and set width and height to 100% and set top and left position to 0.

it will be fixed on the whole screen.

**Note: maybe in some cases you might face a z-index issue so you can define a lower z-index in the background div and higher on other divs**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Background {
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/475/536/354.jpg?hmac=GlMNWcEU96Hkvfl2oszXZwb8vd1fwtQ4rouaQ63UAVM);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.Greetings {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Background"></div>
  <div class="Greetings">
    <h1>
      The City Crown <br /> One of a Kind Place
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="Buttonmenu">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```